# Picture of the day wallpaper not working?

Tags: kubuntu, desktop-background, kde5

My hardisk past away and I need to reinstall Kubuntu in my notebook. First I tried last LTS 22.04, in this version Bing "Picture of the day" worked but because I started to have a lot of problems with the WIFI (that I did not experience with previous versions before) I decided to downgrade and renistall some previous versions. I tried 20.04, 21.04, 21.10, in all of these my WIFI worked fine but "Picture of the day" is not loaded, the only option that work is Earth Sicence (USRA), others option only show the black background default color.

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path         Device      Class          Description
=======================================================
                             system         300E5EV/300E4EV/270E5EV/270E4EV/
/0                           bus            NP270E5E-KD1AR
/0/0                         memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                         processor      Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2117U @
/0/4/6                       memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/4/7                       memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/4/8                       memory         2MiB L3 cache
/0/5                         memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/36                        memory         12GiB System Memory
/0/36/0                      memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 160
/0/36/1                      memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/36/2                      memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 160
/0/36/3                      memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/100                       bridge         3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Cont
/0/100/2                     display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics
/0/100/16                    communication  7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI
/0/100/1a                    bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB
/0/100/1a/1      usb1        bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1                bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/0/100/1a/1/1/3              communication  Bluetooth USB Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1/4              multimedia     WebCam SC-10HDD12636N
/0/100/1b                    multimedia     7 Series/C216 Chipset Family Hig
/0/100/1c                    bridge         7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI
/0/100/1c/0      wlp1s0      network        AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1c.3                  bridge         7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI
/0/100/1c.3/0    enp2s0      network        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethern
/0/100/1d                    bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB
/0/100/1d/1      usb2        bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/0/100/1d/1/1/2              input          USB Receiver
/0/100/1f                    bridge         HM70 Express Chipset LPC Control
/0/100/1f.2                  storage        7 Series Chipset Family 6-port S
/0/100/1f.3                  bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMB
/0/1                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                         system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                         generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/6                         input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/7                         generic        PnP device SYN2601
/0/8                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9             scsi0       storage
/0/9/0.0.0       /dev/sda    disk           240GB KINGSTON SA400S3
/0/9/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1   volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/9/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2   volume         223GiB EXT4 volume
/0/a             scsi2       storage
/0/a/0.0.0       /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD A DU8A5SH
/1                           power          Smart Battery
/2                           power          TBD by ODM
```

I thought it might be a screen resolution issue but I've tried the LiveUSB versions on my desktop with the same results.

Any guidance? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I think this is the problem:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get1_peer_certificate
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_PKEY_get_base_id
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_load_verify_dir
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_load_verify_dir
qt.network.ssl: An error encountered while to set root certificates location: ""
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get1_peer_certificate
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get1_peer_certificate
kf.newstuff.core: "SSL handshake failed"
```

Run

```
plasma-open-settings kcm_desktoptheme
```

from a Konsole. From the window that opens, click on "Get New Plasma Styles". You'll most probably get the error "Loading of providers from file: https://autoconfig.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml failed" and the logs I pasted above will appear in the Konsole.
Unfortunately I don't know how to fix this...